# Type Tax is already defined (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: java, eclipse

When I start the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Racuni.Tax.<init>(DLjava/lang/String;I)V
        at Racuni.dd.main(dd.java:7).
```

Please help.

```
public class dd {
    public static void main (String[] args) {


     Tax t = new Tax(65000,"NJ",3);
     System.out.println(t.dependents + t.grossIncome + t.state);   
    }
}
class Tax extends dd{
    double grossIncome;
    String state;
    int dependents; 



    Tax(double gi, String st, int depen){
        grossIncome= gi;
        state = st;
        dependents = depen;



     }
}
```

Comment: no error above code.

Comment: Try a clean re-compile.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, Java type names usually start with an uppercase letter. Please change your dd class to DD, and so the fileName dd.java to DD.java. And recompile it should work fine.

Comment: I solved this i only need to make new project because public class register class from another package. Java Logic.

Comment: Great, happy to know. :)